# How to isolate a whole CSS file under 1 class umbrella

Tags: css

If I had a hundreds of simple CSS declarations like below, is there a way to encapsulate all of the css so it would only apply if it's parent had the specified class?

```
div{
  color:#ffffff;
}

...

a{
  color:#000000;
}
```

and turn it into something like this?

```
.parentClass{

div{
  color:#ffffff;
}

...

a{
  color:#000000;
}

}// end of parent class
```

instead of having to add .parentClass to every single declaration?

Edit:  I'm not looking for inheritance, I'm looking to basically isolate someone else's css file in a wrapper so it doesn't break the rest of the site it's being used in because they wrote the css using high level elements instead of custom classes.

Comment: I believe you can do something like this with the [is()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) or [where()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where) pseudo-classe, but you'll want to make sure that there is cross-browser-support that meets your needs since these are new-ish.

Comment: There's no way to do this with just plain css syntax?

Comment: It sounds like you are wanting to namespace your CSS so it only affects part of the page. I think there's a way to do this using Shadow DOM, but I've never tried it. Like this: https://blog.bitsrc.io/scoping-css-using-shadow-dom-a548985b73af

Comment: But what I've done in the past is just add a class `myclass` to the root element of the area the CSS should be affecting and then add `.myclass` to the beginning of every selector.

Comment: @Sean I agree. I think it could use a new title/intro to make it clear that it's more about CSS rule isolation and not as much about nesting CSS rules.

Comment: adding the .myClass to every selector is what I'm trying to avoid, but yes that is what I currently do to isolate foreign css.

The shadow DOM might work as well, but that's adding just as much overhead to the process.

Comment: Is this a file under your control that you can edit comfortably or are you trying to avoid editing the file itself?

Comment: I can edit the file yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **NO**.

Only with CSS preprocessors, you can achieve it.
Without preprocessors, you have to add a specific class manually for every selector if you want to nest the styles. There is no shortcut/escape.

Maybe something will be implemented in the future, but the answer as of today is NO.

Comment: This seems to be the most agreed upon solution.  Unfortunate as it is.  Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant answer, but what I've done in the past is to add a class to the local root of the area of the page that CSS belongs to, like `my-component`. Then add `.my-component`  to the beginning of each selector you want to be limited to that area.

I think *maybe* there may be more modern/elegant ways to do this with ShadowDOM or using styled-components, but I'm not familiar with them.